# SonataUserBundle::registerFormMapping() return value

Tags: symfony, sonata-user-bundle

I'm currently creating a website with Symfony3.2.4, I've installed Sonata News Bundle on my website.
I'm trying to having an access to my website but Symfony show me an error.

> Type error: Return value of Sonata\UserBundle\SonataUserBundle::registerFormMapping() must be an instance of Sonata\UserBundle\void, none returned

I don't know from where this error is coming for and how to fix it...
Here is my composer.json :

```
{
"name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
"license": "MIT",
"type": "project",
"description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "AppBundle\\": "src/AppBundle",
        "Application\\": "src/Application"

    },
    "classmap": [ "app/AppKernel.php", "app/AppCache.php" ]
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": { "Tests\\": "tests/"
    },
    "files": [ "vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/VarDumper/Resources/functions/dump.php" ]
},
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.6",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^1.6",
    "doctrine/orm": "^2.5",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "^2.0",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "^5.0.19",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^5.0.0",
    "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "^3.23",
    "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "^3.1",
    "sonata-project/news-bundle": "^3.1",
    "sonata-project/user-bundle": "^3.3",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.1.0",
    "symfony/polyfill-apcu": "^1.0",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^2.6.4",
    "symfony/symfony": "3.4.*",
    "twig/twig": "^1.0||^2.0"
},
"require-dev": {
    "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "^3.0",
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "^3.0",
    "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "^3.0"
},
"scripts": {
    "symfony-scripts": [
        "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget"
    ],
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "@symfony-scripts"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "@symfony-scripts"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist",
    "platform": {
        "php": "5.5.9"
    },
    "sort-packages": true
},
"extra": {
    "symfony-app-dir": "app",
    "symfony-bin-dir": "bin",
    "symfony-var-dir": "var",
    "symfony-web-dir": "web",
    "symfony-tests-dir": "tests",
    "symfony-assets-install": "relative",
    "incenteev-parameters": {
        "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
    },
    "branch-alias": {
        "dev-master": "3.4-dev"
    }
}
```

}

I've got no idea from where this coming this error and hox to fix it.
That's why I request your help ^^.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Did you manage to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with my app. It turned out I was using PHP 7.0 and void is a feature introduced in PHP 7.1 (http://php.net/releases/7_1_0.php).

Please double check you are using PHP 7.1+.

Comment: It is awful to strict PHP to 7.1... For instance, my hosting provider does not support PHP 7.1 yet, so what should I do?...

Comment: @Alexander I think that only way is to downgrade version of SonataUserBundle (at least in the context of this thread).

I've tried to reproduce the problem with the same composer.json as the one in the question and I've experienced some problems. I use PHP 5.6.34 for this.

1. On project level: `platform contains PHP 5.5.9 which is in conflict with minimal dependency PHP version >=5.6.`

2. On dependency level: `sonata-project/news-bundle 3.4.0 requires php ^5.6 || ^7.0.`

After version update in platform to 5.6.34 I get this error: `sonata-project/user-bundle 3.4.0 requires php ^7.1.`

Comment: I see. Thanks bro!